# Push notifications on Apple Watch Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

Will Push Notifications get displayed on the Apple Watch simulator ?
I have run an app that displays push notifications on iPhone 5C. An Apple Watch app is made as a target of this app.

I usually get Push Notifications on this iPhone 5C while any movement is made in front of a live streaming camera. So is it possible to display the same on Apple Watch Simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No push notifications require a **device token**, which is not available on the simulator.

You will receive this message: "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator"

You need to test on device, to test Push Notifications.

You can use this library to simulate remote notifications though: https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications

Comment: Suppose a movement is caused in front of camera,then after that I run the watch app and control enters- 

    (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler { 

completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);

Comment: Question is how to trigger local or remote notification in watch not about supported or not